# Generate Tile Map from array

Tags: c#, enums, tile

I've been thinking about trying to create a RPG game, a simple game with movement, pick up items, and open doors.

I've been thinking for a long time about the tile map engine, but i can't find anything that works :/

Basically what i'm trying to accomplish is i have an `enum`, like:

```cs
public enum tileSort { Dirt, Grass, Stone, Empty }
```

And when the engine runs through the array, which will have 0's, 1's, etc, I'm thinking about a switch statement, something like:

```cs
switch(tileSort) 
{ 
    case '0':  tileList.Add(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Tiles/grass")) 
}
```

The problem is that I have no idea on how to make this possible, all that I've been able to create is an engine that runs through and generates depending on which content you load first into the game.

I know this is confusing, as I'm not good at explaining myself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are on the right track.  What you may want to do next, is figure out how to Load/Save the tile map data to disk, instead of specifying the map in your code.

Comment: Maybe by using a StreamReader?
Now my only problem is how to put the code together :/

Comment: You may be interested in this:  http://www.mapeditor.org/   You can create/edit/save maps in a data format, and then load them into your game.  (Examples on how to load are easy to find online)

Comment: Thanks, but i can't find a download for the .tmx loader lib D:

Comment: https://github.com/zachmu/tiled-xna

Comment: I have everything fixed, i have a map.tmx, and i have every necessary code added, but when i run my game, it says that "level1" is wrong directory...i've tried things like keeping it in a folder, outside of a folder, but nothing works :/ I have also changed the "Compile" to "None", and "Copy to Output" to "Copy if newer", what am i doing wrong?? D:

Comment: "Always Copy" the file over to your bin directory.  If it is in the root of your bin directory, you should be able to load it simply by the filename.  Make sure the file is in your bin directory, if not, just put it there yourself for now.

Comment: I did, but i also get: "Value can't be Null" on `if (!result.Objects.ContainsKey(objects.Name))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use some tools to help you:

- http://jdevh.com/2012/06/01/griddy2d/
- http://github.com/zachmu/tiled-xna
- http://xnafantasy.wordpress.com/2008/11/22/xna-map-editor-version-30-released/

I'm sure you can find many others.

About the snippets of code you wrote, you don't want to call

```
Content.Load<Texture2D>("Tiles/grass")
```

multiple times for a single texture. Load each texture only once and print the same resource multiple times. You could have something like this:

```
var tileList = new List<Texture2D>();
string[] tiles = { "dirt", "grass", "stone", "empty" };

foreach (var s in tiles) {
    tileList.Add(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Tiles/" + s));
}
```

Now each texture is loaded only once, and you can access it using `tileList[index].`

The next step is to print the tiles on the screen. I'll assume you have loaded your tiles into a 2 dimensional array with the tile indexes.

```
int[,] tileMap = {{1, 2, 0}, {0, 1, 2}, {3, 3, 1},};

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        spriteBatch.Draw(tileList[tileMap[i, j]], new Vector2D(50*i, 50*j), Color.White);
        // Assuming the tiles are 50x50 pixels
```

**This tutorial teaches what you want with more details: http://www.xnaresources.com/?page=Tutorial:TileEngineSeries:1**

Comment: thanks, but how do i make a certain tile with collision, or make it movable for events??