# Creating a tiled map in unity using a 2D array and a text file

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am trying to read in a text tile and use it to display a map when the game it run.
I am having a problem when it reads a number that is larger than 0 (I think).

The Objects in the first column will be displayed but nothing else will. Again I think its because it is the tiles[0] position.

This is the error I get:

IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
Map.loadMap () (at Assets/Photon Unity Networking/Scripts/Overworld/Map.cs:49)

Here is the Map file

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 6 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 4 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 0
0 5 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 2 2 7 2 2 1 0
0 1 1 2 7 2 2 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 5 0
0 1 2 2 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 2 2 4 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 6 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

and here is my Map code.

```
int X, Y;
public int mapHeight;
public int mapWidth;

GameObject mapTile;

GameObject [,] mapArray;
public GameObject [] Tiles = new GameObject[8]; //this is an array of the tile objects

/* UNITY FUNCTIONS */
void Awake(){

}

void Start () {
    loadMap ();
}

void Update () {

}


/* DATA MANAGEMENT */
void loadMap(){
    string input = File.ReadAllText( Application.dataPath + 
                                            "/Resources/Maps/map0.txt" );

    mapHeight = 9;
    mapWidth = 15;
    mapArray = new GameObject [mapHeight,mapWidth];

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    foreach (var row in input.Split('\n'))
    {
        foreach (var col in row.Trim().Split(' '))
        {
            mapArray[i, j] = Tiles[int.Parse(col.Trim())]; //Get the GameObject from the Tiles
            mapTile = mapArray[i, j];                      //array and att it to the map array
            GameObject.Instantiate(mapTile, new Vector3(i, j, 0),
                                   Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0)); //display it on screen
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: Launch the game with debugger attached (hit run in monodevelop) then you'll see where it crashes and what the values of i and j are. You can also set a breakpoint and step through to see where it's going wrong. You may want to add assertions to test your assumptions that there are 9 rows and 15 columns.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to lie in your iteration of each tile. Iterating your array like this may fix the problem.

```
foreach (var row in Map))
{
    foreach (var col in row)
    {
        mapArray[i, j] = Tiles[int.Parse(col.Trim())]; //Get the GameObject from the Tiles
        mapTile = mapArray[i, j];                      //array and att it to the map array
        GameObject.Instantiate(mapTile, new Vector3(i, j, 0),
                               Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0)); //display it on screen
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

I recommend looking on this post for some guidance:
[Generate Tile Map from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245458/generate-tile-map-from-array)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem. Here is the code for those who may need help. I have also added code that takes the maps width and height from the first two lines.

The map txt file now looks like this.

```
10 
17
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 6 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 4 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 0
0 5 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 2 2 7 2 2 1 1 0
0 1 1 2 2 7 2 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 5 1 0
0 1 2 2 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 2 2 4 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 6 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The function now looks like this.

```
void loadMap(){

    bool isMap = false;
    string input = File.ReadAllText( Application.dataPath + 
                                        "/Photon Unity Networking" +
                                            "/Resources/Maps/map0.txt" );

    string[] f = input.Split(new string[] {"\n", "\r", "\r\n"}, 
                             System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    if(f[0].Length > 0 && f[1].Length > 0)
    {
        int.TryParse(f[0], out mapHeight);
        int.TryParse(f[1], out mapWidth);
    }

    if (mapWidth > 0 && mapHeight > 0) {
                    mapArray = new GameObject [mapHeight, mapWidth];
                    int y = 0, x = 0;
                    foreach (var row in input.Split('\n')) {
                            x = 0;
                            foreach (var col in row.Trim().Split(' ')) {
                                    if(int.Parse (col.Trim ()) < 8){
                                        mapArray [y, x] = Tiles [int.Parse (col.Trim ())];  
                                        mapTile = mapArray [y, x];
                                        GameObject.Instantiate (mapTile, new Vector3 (x, mapHeight-y, 0),
                                                                Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 0));
                                        x++;
                                        isMap = true;
                                    }else{ isMap = false; }
                            }
                            if(isMap == true){ y++; }
                    }
    }
}
```